# How to pass JSON data from Node js route to script inside an html file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to populate a  dropdown in my index html with data from a mongodb collection. I have populating code that looks like this:

```
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
          for (element in mongoData){
            var option = document.createElement('option');
            option.innerHTML = element;
            option.value = element;
            document.getElementById('Active_Sessions').append(option);
          }
        });
      </script>
```

and in app.js, my route is as follows:

```
    app.use("/",(req,res) => {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html")
     })
```

I need to pass the JSON object 'mongoData' to this html, and am not sure how to do this. The 'mongoData' will be a JSON of some data collected from a given collection.

One solution I thought of but haven't implemented yet is to write out this mongodata to a text file or a csv file or something like that from the app.js, and then read in the file from my populating script. I feel like this would be bad form though and not very secure.

Another option I thought of is to try and connect to the mongoose server within the populating script, but when I tried this, it didn't work so I've kinda assumed that this is not possible.

Something I've looked into before posting this is using res.render() to send the JSON, but I don't really understand what templating is and would rather not have to learn about all of that if I can avoid that.

Is there an elegant solution to this?

Comment: You can set another route to get `mongoData` and make an `AJAX` call to that route.

Comment: Could you elaborate further on that? I have no previous experience with AJAx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would change your data in your server eg through a template engine.

Or you can build something similar to do the same. Dummy logic:

1. Readfile with fs module.
2. Use regex to replace/insert your content (eg from your object).
3. Send result to client.

---

**UPDATE**: A simple example for a custom template engine.

First a simple html file - index.html (please notice $replace_me):

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="circle">
      $replace_me

      <div class="square">
        something else
      </div>
    </div>
  <body>
</html>
```

In our node server we could do something like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');

//used sync for clean demo, use async in production
var _html_cont = fs.readFileSync('index.html', {encoding: 'utf-8'});

//dynamic content to replace
var _repl = "<div>I am new!</div>";

//actually replace it
var _im_regex = new RegExp("\\$replace_me", "gm");
_html_cont = _html_cont.replace(_im_regex, _repl);

 //send result to client
 res.writeHead(200, { 'content-type': 'text/html' });
 res.write(_html_cont);
 res.end();
```

Comment: When you say use regex to insert content, how would I do this? Everything I lookup tells me that it is not possible to read serverside files in js.